# Amazon EC2 php/fedora htaccess mod_rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, amazon-ec2, fedora

Amazon EC2 with Fedora, there are 2 instances of the httpd conf, the doc root is automatically set as /home/webuser/helloworld/conf/httpd.conf and  the default (which is also there) is /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf .  Mod rewrite is enabled with both, we are in drupal, the .htaccess is in the folder it needs to be (on Drupal) and it loads the homepage and other static files fine, but it WILL not use htaccess.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Restart Apache, nothing.  Restart the box..fixed. wtf?